# Tomcat in k8s pod and db in cloud - slow connection

Tags: kubernetes, tomcat, cloud

I have tomcat, zookeeper and kafka deployled in local k8s(kind) cluster. The database is remote i.e. in cloud. The pages load very slowly.

But when i moved tomcat outside of the pod and started manually with zk and kafka in local k8s cluster and db in remote cloud the pages are loading fine.

Why is Tomcat very slow when inside a Kubernetes pod?

Comment: Did you put limits to the resources which Tomcat could use as a Pod?

Comment: check to resource limit that you have put for the zk and kafka.

Comment: @And0 I didn’t put any limits on Tomcat but did for zk and Kafka. My docker desktop shows 21GB RAM allocated to it. When I ran manually I saw it using 8GB.

Comment: @harish I have less than 1GB for Zk and 1.6GB for Kafka. So it’s not much compared to 21GB I gave for docker desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, a program running in a container can run as fast as a program running on the host machine.

In practice, there are many things that can affect the performance.

- When running on Windows or macOS (for instance with Docker Desktop), container doesn't run directly on the machine, but in a small Linux virtual machine. This VM will add a bit of overhead, and it might not have as much CPU and RAM as the host environment. One way to have a look at the resource usage of containers is to use `docker stats`; or `docker run -ti --pid host alpine` and then use classic UNIX tools like `free`, `top`, `vmstat`, ... to see the resource usage in the VM.
- In most environments (at least with Docker, and with Kubernetes clusters in their most common default configurations), containers run without resource constraints and limits. However, it is fairly common (and, in fact, highly recommended!) to set resource requests and limits when running containers on Kubernetes. You can check resource limits of a pod with `kubectl describe`. If metrics-server is installed (which is recommended, even on dev/staging environments), you can check resource usage with `kubectl top`. Tools like `k9s` will show you resource requests, limits, and usage in a comprehensive way (as long as the data is available; i.e. you still need to install metrics-server to obtain pod metrics, for instance).
- In addition to the VM overhead described above, if the container does a lot of I/O (whether it's disk or network), there might be a bit of overhead in comparison to a native process. This can become noticeable if the container writes on the container copy-on-write filesystem (instead of a volume), especially when using the device-mapper storage driver.
- Applications that use "live reload" techniques (that automatically rebuild or restart when source code is edited) are particularly prone to this I/O issue, because there are unfortunately no efficient methods to watch file modifications across a virtual machine boundary. This means that many web frameworks exhibit extreme performance degradations when running in containers on Mac or Windows when the source code is mounted to the container.
- In addition to these factors, there can be other subtle differences that might affect the overall performance of a containerized application. When observing performance issues, it is very helpful to use a profiler (or some kind of APM solution) to see which parts of the code take longer to execute. If no profiler or APM is available, try to execute individual portions of the code independently to compare their performance. For instance, have a small piece of code that executes a single query to the database; or executes a single task from a job queue, etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Joetazzo, my tomcat starts in 12 min when deployed inside a container vs 3 min when started manually. I go to browser and see if http://localhost:8080 loads anything. But before 12 min nothing shows up iwith container tomcat. Also all tests are making http rest calls and timing out with container deployment. I have 10-12 min timeout configured in tests. Also, I am writing logs to volumes and don’t have any live/hot loading

Comment: In the case of Tomcat, and with specific JVM versions, you might also have an issue with randomness. [This article](https://blog.georgovassilis.com/2015/09/13/tomcat-starts-slowly-in-docker-container/) suggests to set `JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom`.